# replace 0 that is in between exactly two numbers in a column

Tags: pandas

I only want to replace 0 which lies between exactly two numbers with its average value.
My dataset looks like below:

```
time    value
9:45:00 0
10:00:00    0
10:15:00    0
10:30:00    10
10:45:00    0
11:00:00    10
11:15:00    10
11:30:00    0
11:45:00    10
12:00:00    0
12:15:00    0
12:30:00    0
12:45:00    10
13:00:00    0
13:15:00    0
```

I want it to look like this:

```
time    value
9:45:00 0
10:00:00    0
10:15:00    0
10:30:00    10
10:45:00    10
11:00:00    10
11:15:00    10
11:30:00    10
11:45:00    10
12:00:00    0
12:15:00    0
12:30:00    0
12:45:00    10
13:00:00    0
13:15:00    0
```

in this, since the 0 between 11:45 to 12:45 is not exactly between two numbers (ie multiple zeros), we are not filling in these values

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```py
from io import StringIO as sio
data = sio("""
time    value
9:45:00 0
10:00:00    0
10:15:00    0
10:30:00    10
10:45:00    0
11:00:00    10
11:15:00    10
11:30:00    0
11:45:00    10
12:00:00    0
12:15:00    0
12:30:00    0
12:45:00    10
13:00:00    0
13:15:00    0
""")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')

df['flag_to_fill'] = (df['value']==0) & (df['value'].shift(1)!=0) & (df['value'].shift(-1)!=0)

df.loc[df['flag_to_fill'], 'value'] = 0.5*(df['value'].shift(1) + df['value'].shift(-1))

df
```